# basic image processing with numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

I'm just testing very basic stuff about image manipulation with numpy ndarray data structure and matplotlib for show the image. I created a 2-dimensional array with np.zeros((n,m)) function where store my pixel, to keep things easy I'm just working in grayscale so I only need one value to represent my pixel. this is my code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix= np.zeros((4,4))
print(matrix)
plt.matshow(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.gray) #plot matrix 

matrix+=128 #increase each pixel value by 128
print(matrix) #print the content of matrix
plt.matshow(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.gray) #plot matrix
```

What I expect from this code is that the first plot will be totally black because each "pixel" has value 0, and there's no problem here. Then I increase the pixel from 0 to 128 so the second plot should be totally grey, but is still black. Is like no operation is executed but matrix effectively has changed(checked from the print function).

So I tried to modify just some pixel "manually":

```
matrix[0,0]=255
matrix[0,3]=255
matrix[3,0]=255
matrix[3,3]=255

plt.matshow(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.gray) #plot matrix
```

and now 4 pixels are white. 
There are some aspects that I'm totally missing and I think that are related to numpy and some stuff about ndarray and how is managed.

There's anyone can explain me why this happens? thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default, the colors of the color map are mapped to the minimum and maximum values of the data to be plotted.  To override this, use the arguments `vmin` and `vmax`:

```
plt.matshow(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```